# Qt Designer: Cannot change the font size

Tags: qt-designer

I have some labels on the tab (i.e. tabWidget), when I change the fontsize, it does change BUT when I save the file, they all switch back to something else (default or whatever). 
What is going on here?!

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to set the font using a style sheet. Some time ago, I was looking for information and I found a solution reading the Qt documentation and using some official Qt examples.

Here you have an example. Change the css following your own requierements.

**.pro file**

```
HEADERS       = mainwindow.h 
FORMS         = mainwindow.ui 
RESOURCES     = stylesheet.qrc
SOURCES       = main.cpp \
                mainwindow.cpp \
```

**stylesheet.qrc**

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/">
    <file>qss/cool.qss</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Q_INIT_RESOURCE(stylesheet);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QtWidgets>

#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindow();

    Ui::MainWindow ui;

private:
    void loadStyleSheet(const QString &sheetName);
};

#endif
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include <QtWidgets>

#include "mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow()
{
    ui.setupUi(this);
    loadStyleSheet("Cool");
}

void MainWindow::loadStyleSheet(const QString &sheetName)
{
    QFile file(":/qss/" + sheetName.toLower() + ".qss");
    file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
    QString styleSheet = QString::fromLatin1(file.readAll());

    qApp->setStyleSheet(styleSheet);
}
```

**Finally, the most important file, cool.qss:**

```
QTabWidget::pane { /* The tab widget frame */
    border: 2px solid #C2C7CB;
}

QTabWidget::tab-bar {
    left: 5px; /* move to the right by 5px */
}

/* Style the tab using the tab sub-control. Note that
    it reads QTabBar _not_ QTabWidget */
QTabBar::tab {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #E1E1E1, stop: 0.4 #DDDDDD,
                                stop: 0.5 #D8D8D8, stop: 1.0 #D3D3D3);
    border: 2px solid #C4C4C3;
    border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB; /* same as the pane color */
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    /* You should change min-width according to the
        lenght of your tab text */
    min-width: 14ex;
    padding: 4px;
    font: bold 14px;
}

QTabBar::tab:selected, QTabBar::tab:hover {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #fafafa, stop: 0.4 #f4f4f4,
                                stop: 0.5 #e7e7e7, stop: 1.0 #fafafa);
}

QTabBar::tab:selected {
    border-color: #9B9B9B;
    border-bottom-color: #C2C7CB; /* same as pane color */
}

QTabBar::tab:!selected {
    margin-top: 2px; /* make non-selected tabs look smaller */
}
```

In this file you have more code than necessary, but maybe it is important to play with all the properties.

Anyway, you need to change the following line according to your requirements.

```
font: bold 14px;
```

It is also important to check the value for min-width is enough for the font size.